# android: dynamic values in spinner from my web api in dot net

Tags: android, sql-server, spinner

My question to you all is can i add values to a spinner from MSSQL database via a web API?
i am able to add static values. which are defined in the array adapter.
Is there a way to add values from a database to a spinner?

```
<string name="select">Choose a country</string>

<string name="select2">Choose an item</string>

<string name="button_label">Submit</string>



<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Greece</item>

    <item>United Kingdom</item>

    <item>Italy</item>

    <item>France</item>

    <item>Germany</item>

    <item>Turkey</item>

    <item>Poland</item>

    <item>India</item>

</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch data from WEB API in Json/xml then parse it and store as `ArrayList<String>` or `List<String>` then pass this ArrayList to ArrayAdapter.

Try like this

```
    // Spinner Drop down elements from WEB API
    List<String> lables = getDatafromWEB();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

For more details refer this [**android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/)

Comment: this is an example of php i am trying mssql through dot net

Comment: yes i know but difference is just fetching data after that all same. so you just edit AsyncClass as you want to parse data from your webapi.